# Initial configuration GSM Modem in Raspberry PI using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, gsm

I am a newbie in NodeJS framwork and currently i am working on a project where i want to establish connectivity to my cloud application and make some API calls.for that i want to make initial configuration to establish a connection on my gsm modem.

1. How to search for the presense of Sim card in gsm modem
2. How to receive the APN and configure the gsm sim card(APN,subnet,gateway etc)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use WvDial to help you find the GSM Modem.  Here is tutorial for doing so with a USB Modem: https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-setup-usb-3g-modem-raspberry-pi-using-usbmodeswitch-and-wvdial

   WvDial helps configure the PPP connection.
2. The APN is dependent on your cellular provider.  You should review your provider's documentation or reach out to them for the necessary details.